# Puppeteer finds selector locally but not on heroku

Tags: heroku, puppeteer

I have a weird error whereby puppeteer finds a selector locally but not when run in Heroku.

I click on a select search box which then reveals a list of select items, but for some reason puppeteer is able to find all selectors in the list except for the last one, only when run on Heroku. It finds all selectors when run locally.

I've tried waiting for the selector but that still doesn't help, it just cannot seem to find it. It works for other accounts that have a longer list of items.

error: `failed to parse stock level page { TimeoutError: waiting for selector "#siteList_chosen > div > ul > li:nth-child(19)" failed: timeout`

so in the image below, the selector fails to find `data-option-array-index="18"`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find selector like this you can use:

```
[data-option-array-index="18"]
```

instead of

```
li:nth-child()
```

Also you can use less strict selector to get all elements like this:

```
await page.$$('.chosen-results li')
```

this will get all li elements - then you can iterate over this using .forEach (but first you need to convert NodeList to Array).